# How can I set X labels in MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, android-studio, mpandroidchart

I'm making a horizontal barChart using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) by PhilJay.

I have a problem with `aligning x label` items.

[image]

I want current x labels (black numbers) to be red numbers I marked up!

Currently missing 5 and 6 :(

**Here's my code.**

```
XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
xAxis.setAxisMinimum(start);
xAxis.setDrawAxisLine(false); 
xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM); 


String[] xAxisVals = new String[]{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"}; 
xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(xAxisVals));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the below property for labelling x-axis

xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(false);